# Enforcing consistent component behavior in Angular applications

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns

What techniques do people use to achieve consistency in behaviors that Angular components should have within an application?  Especially with projects that are very large or have geographically distributed teams?  Things like:

- All components should set the page title
- All top level components should be resilient to page refreshes
- All components should ensure that they unsubscribe to things on `ngOnDestroy()`

Is it worth putting some of these things into an abstract base component?  Something that gets injected with `Title` and `ActivateRoute` and a subscription tracker, and provides the base implementation for `ngOnInit()` and `ngOnDestroy()`, and forces subclasses to implement methods like `title(): string` and `subscriptions(): any[]`?

Is this a better thing for composition?  If so, how do you enforce components written by a distributed team of engineers to inject (and appropriately use) a TitleService, or RefreshManager, or SubscriptionTracker?

Is it sufficient to preach convention on the team?  Define code structure standards that all top level components must follow?  If so, how are these enforced?

Decorators seem like the **could** be useful in addressing some of this problem space.  Creating a decorator like:

```
@PageTitle("Foo Title")
@Component({...})
export class FooComponent {
}
```

that is backed by a function that wraps `ngOnInit()` with code to store existing title and set "Foo Title", and then code that wraps `noOnDestroy()` to restore the original title.  But limitations of decorators seem to preclude injecting services, and the above example would still require that the FooComponent implements `OnInit, OnDestroy` for the decorator to be correctly applied at build time.

So to summarize: how are people currently solving this problem?

1. Abstract base component of all common functionality
2. Several common utilities injected into every component
3. Coding standards that enforce consistent (duplicate) code across components
4. Something else

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question @Jeff. This is an interesting topic. Here are my two cents. I'm sure others have more to say.

1. Abstract base component of all common functionality

I use an event in angular1 and observable in angular5. Ex.

```
title: Subject<boolean>
```

Basically, you have a common service build with `title` observable. Your other team can subscribe to this common service. This service supplies methods to update the title of the page and also notify others when the title changes.

2. Several common utilities injected into every component

If you have many services/components, you can bundle them as a module, and then you and your other team member can import this module as one of the third party modules.

```
import { MyCommonModule }      from 'my-common-module';
```

This bundle doesn't have routes but can contain any visual components or non-visual services.

3. Coding standards that enforce consistent code across components

If all common modules are sitting inside the above `MyCommonModule`, then you don't need to have too much concern of the consistency, since there are not many people touching that repo/module

4. Something else

Coding a module can be different than coding an app, so you might need to have your own build system so that you can test it locally as well as pushing to npm for distribution.

Comment: For the first point you say "Your other team can subscribe to this common service. This service supplies methods to update the title of the page and also notify others when the title changes."  I get that, but it doesn't solve my original problem.  Every individual component needs to remember to inject the service, to update the string in `ngOnInit`, maybe save the old title and reset via the title service on `ngOnDestroy`...all boilerplate, all duplicated from component to component when it's remembered.  And a single example of many things that you might want consistent.

Comment: I see, Jeff. I totally forget that. Maybe you can code a sample class that other component can be derived from, or certain interface so that others won't forget to include. The problem is that it might be hard for others to use your class as their base class because most of UI developer is using composition pattern and the web is moving so fast. But if you are confident enough, I don't see why not a root class or component.

Comment: Just another note to your comment Jeff. I feel that `ngOnInit` and `ngOnDestroy` shouldn't be wrapped inside your framework. Because this is something the javascript class (or from Angular) offers us as a programming mechanism. Just imaging if you did your way, what if another developer what to add an extra line to `ngOnInit`? They still need to re-code. Therefore why not just put it into the documentation or sample demo code section. Another extreme, `import ... from`, you can't abstract this, right? :)